# On an argument concerning whether weather *it* is truly an expletive

Tags: semantics, pronouns

[Morgan (1968)](https://i.imgur.com/ISfEifS.jpg) claims that many instances of unstressed *it* are meaningless. He offers the following argument: the pronoun *he* in (1a) can refer to either John or Bill but the gap in (1b) can only refer to John; that is, coreference with the previous subject is enforced. Since (2a) can be paraphrased with (2b) and it is absurd to say that the subjects mean the same thing, the pronoun *it* is meaningless.

> (1a) John wanted Bill to go to see a movie with him but he didn't have tickets
>
> (1b) John wanted Bill to go to see a movie with him but _ didn't have tickets
>
> (2a) It is easy to respect John but it is hard to like him
>
> (2b) It is easy to respect John but _ hard to like him

I remain unconvinced. First, (1b) and (2b) are not parallel as far as ellipsis goes: in the latter the finite verb is deleted too.

But perhaps there is an argument here. I'm not a native speaker so I'll have to rely on your judgements. It is argued whether weather verbs or verbs of physical feeling take a meaningless subject or a pronoun that resumes a locative PP. Do (3a) and (4a) sound noticeably better to you than (3b) and (4b)? (Presumably, if they sound equally good it would show that these verbs in fact take expletive subjects.)

> (3a) It hurt around his eyes but it itched around hers
>
> (3b) It hurt around his eyes but _ itched around hers
>
> (4a) It rained in Boston but it snowed in New York
>
> (4a) It rained in Boston but _ snowed in New York

Comment: How do you define "expletive" clearly enough to be able to distinguish a "true" one?

Comment: @jlawler There are prosodic cues that distinguish the first and second occurrence of *there* in *there is something there*, i.e. the first cannot bear a pitch accent or be accompanied by a pointing gesture, even if one rejects intuitions about what is and isn't meaningful, which is a radical view, and quite clearly inconsistent with most contemporary work on theoretical linguistics.

Comment: Ah, you mean a referential pronoun. I don't care about Morgan's argument, but in (3) _it_ can be either referential or dummy. If it's referential (referring to _the headset_, for instance), then _it_ can be deleted under coreference; if it's a dummy, I'd repeat it. (4), on the other hand, can't be referential, and (4b) seems grammatical (though, again, I'd repeat it).